# Send JSON dictionary and Image with Socket.io

Tags: ios, swift, express, socket.io

I want to send this JSON to my iOS app from socket.io, I have googled for but not get any perfect answer, This is the JSON i want to share to client app, How can i emit this ?

```
{
    "message_id": "001",
    "type": ["add", "remove"],
    "student": {
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "john",
        "standard": "11",
    },
    "profile": {
        "thumb": Image (base64-encoded),
    }
}
```

Is there any way to share this? How can I do this? I am new to socket.io, kindly help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following client to receive the json data that you emit from server.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

**In Server:**

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );
var io = socket.listen( server );


io.sockets.on( 'connection', function() {

console.log( "Client connected" );

let data = {
    "message_id": "001",
    "type": ["add", "remove"],
    "student": {
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "john",
        "standard": "11",
    },
    "profile": {
        "thumb": Image (base64-encoded),
    }
};

socket.emit( 'message', data );

  });

});

server.listen(8080);
```

You can find various options to emit the message to the clients in the following link

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

**In your IOS client:**

```
import Foundation

let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:8080")
socket.on("message") { data, ack in
    println("Message for you! \(data?[0])")
    ack?("I got your message, and I'll send my response") 
    socket.emit("response", "Hello!")
}
socket.connect()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, how can I add image (base 64) in JSON ?

Comment: It is not recommended to send base64 strings in JSON objects. Its a bad practice. alternatively, you can send some url of the image in JSON so that you can use that image at later point.